# React Native with TypeScript: How to set up globals in setup.js?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

I'm building a React Native app with TypeScript.

I want to use [jest-fetch-mock](https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock). In the documentation it says to create `setup.js` file and add

```
global.fetch = require("jest-fetch-mock");
```

in it. I did that. But I get the error:

```
[ts] Cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.
```

So I googled and found out that I just have to import something to fix this (which is fine, since I need imports for setting `NativeModules.ReactLocalization` for using [localization](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization) anyway).

Then I get the error:

```
[ts] Cannot find name 'global'.
```

So I googled some more and found this 'fix':

```
// Change to file to setup.ts and
const globalAny: any = global;
```

But it throws the same error and now I'm stuck. How can I set a global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why typescript compiles `.js` files?

If you have `setup.ts` file: try to add `declare var global: any;` before `global.fetch = ...`.

However, I suggest you to use typings for your project:

```
npm i -D @types/node @types/jest
```

Then extending `global` object will look like this:

```
declare module NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    fetch: GlobalFetch
  }
}

global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock');
```